# Is there a way to have method annotations passed on to sub-classes?

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea, annotations, java-annotations

I have a few custom method annotations used on methods which are typically overridden. For example, let's consider something like an `@Async` annotation:

```
public class Base {
  @Async
  public void foo() {
  }
}
```

Is there a way to signal to the compiler and/or IDE that a method annotation should follow into overridden versions of a method, so that when someone extends `Base` and overrides `foo()`, the `@Async` annotation is automatically inserted, similarly to how `@Override` is automatically inserted by most IDEs?

If there's no general way of hinting this, is there an IntelliJ/Android Studio specific way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Annotation is inherited if it is marked with other annotation `@Inherited`. So, if annotation `@Async` that you have given as an example is yours just do the following:

```
@Inherited
// other annotations (e.g. Retention, Target etc)
@interface Async {
}
```

If however this is not your annotation you the only way to make it visible in subclass is to create a trivial implementation of `foo()` in this subclass and mark this method with this annotation, e.g.

```
public class Base {
  @Async
  public void foo() {
  }
}
public class Child extends Base {
  // Trivial implementation needed only to make the annotation available here. 
  @Async
  public void foo() {
      super.foo();
  }
}
```